# How would I store values in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to store non "h" values in an array. So to give you a background, I need to make a basic cash register that accepts 5 items in an array with a price on them. Nevertheless, some items will have HST(tax) included with them. To know which items have tax and which don't. The user will press h or H before or after entering the dollar amount. I have stored the values with the HST in an array, but how would I store the non-HST values?

Sample input:

```
4.565H
H2.3435
4.565h
5.234
5.6576h
```

Sample Output:

```
HST Values:
4.565
2.3435
4.565
5.6576

Non-HST Values
5.234
```

---

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press any key to start");
        String key = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
        System.out.println("Up to 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

        // Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;
 
        // Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
        double[] numbers = new double[5];

        // Create a boolean variable to use it in the while loop
        boolean go = true;

        while (go) {           
            String value = inp.nextLine();      
            value = value.toLowerCase();
  
            // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
            int indexOfh = value.indexOf('h');

            boolean containsh = (indexOfh == 0 || indexOfh == value.length() - 1);
            
            if (containsh) { //Validate h at beginning or end
                numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
                index++;
                System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
            }

            counter++;
            if (counter == 5) {
                go = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("HST Values:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with storing the non-HST values in an array in the same way you did for the HST values?

Comment: How about `if(containsh) {} else { ... store it ... }`?

Comment: You also probably want a for loop rather than a while loop if you are limiting input values

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to work with `ArrayList` instead:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press any key to start");
        String key = inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
        System.out.println("Up to 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

        // Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
        int counter = 0;
 
        // Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
        ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();

        // Create a boolean variable to use it in the while loop
        boolean go = true;

        while (go) {           
            String value = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            int indexOfH = value.indexOf('h');

            if (indexOfH == 0 || indexOfH == value.length() - 1) { //Validate h at beginning or end
                numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", "")));
                System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
            }

            counter++;
            if (counter == 5)
                go = false;
        }

        System.out.println("HST Values:");
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use Arrays.list

Comment: Then there is no safe solution; arrays are unresizable in Java. You can do `System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1, size - index)` but this is unsafe (by the way, this is the main instruction of the `ArrayList.add()` method)

Answer (score 0):

You just need two arrays, one for H values and the other for non H. Why not use lists? Lists would be better

However, if the requirement is arrays, just store the h values by checking 'H' values like you have, and if index of 'H' is -1 that means the value does not contain h, then just add those to the other array and print it out as well at the end.